# Slow interaction of blue prism process with office 365 Excel

Tags: blueprism

I have a process that is using Excel 365. It was fast with previous versions of Excel. I noticed how slow it is to find the cell and paste data into it; more than 40 seconds in some cases. Delay accumulates as I have to do that to many cells. I am using Excel object in blue prism. What can I do to change things to recognize Excel cell faster?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with Blue Prism update. the update was not installed correctly on the machine that some libraries to handle office were not functioning well. the issue was resolved with a fresh install of that update.